# Updating global variables from try block

Tags: python

I would like to update the global variable status after the try block runs successful. Is there a way to do so. The code below seem not work as intended.

```
status = "unsuccessful"

def test_func(a, b):
    global status
    try:
        return a + b
        status = "success"
    except TypeError:
        print("Wrong")


print(test_func(20, 1))
print(status)
```

Comment: you try to do things after `return`, that is not how `return` works.

Comment: `return` exit the method, put it just after `status = "success"`

Comment: It works. Thanks. Post it  as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing here is because status = "success" will never be reached. If your code enters the try block it'll return a+b and exit the block. Putting the status = "success" line above the return line will fix your issue.

```
    try:
        status = "success"
        return a + b
```